# present method shows blank view controller

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm new to iOS app development and just basically trying to create a real app based on the tutorial and research that I've been studying. Basically, I have a view controller, followed by a navigation controller and a table view controller (with static cells) linked to that navigation controller.

The goal here is to just simply present the table view controller based on a condition (if something exists, present table view controller, otherwise don't), and while I can get it to show up, it's blank. It doesn't have any of the labels or text boxes that I added.

So for example, here's what I have inside of my original view controller. What I'm attempting is to check whether or not profileExists and if it does, present the table view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Check if user has a profile. If so, go to view page; otherwise, bring up new profile view.
    if profileExists != 1 {
        // Create new profile page.
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateProfileController") as? CreateProfileViewController {

            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        print("Need to create new profile page")
    }

}
```

I have two classes -- one called CreateProfileViewController (which my navigation controller is assigned to), and I have a CreateProfileTableViewController class which is what my table view controller is assigned to. The storyboard ID of my navigation controller is `CreateProfileController`

Based on that code, I would expect the table view controller to be presented, and also the labels and text boxes that reside on that table view controller. What am I possibly doing wrong to where the table view controller is blank?

**EDIT:**

Updated to include CreateProfileTableViewController class:

```
//
//  CreateProfileTableViewController.swift
//  Steady Marketing
//
//  Created by Alton on 5/11/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 SteadyMarketing. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CreateProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }

    /*
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Where is the storyboard comes from in your code? Also you must call the self.present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

before showing any basic tableviewcontroller we need to do something.

**Step 1:**

configure datasource and delegate.

**step 2:**

Make some rows using basic 2 datasource methods.

1. numberofrows. in your case its 0;
2. cellForAtIndexPath. in your case i can see it's comment out.

There are plenty of resources.Right now here is a link

[iOS & Swift Tutorial: UITableViewController-ralfebert](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/#storyboard_table_contents)

Comment: Could you please accept my answer  if this is helpful?

Comment: i ended up removing the numberofrows and cellforindexpath methods to get the static tables to show, but i REALL Y appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all your tableView need some sections. Atleast 1 would be good.
After that you want to have some cells in each section, so put at least 1 there as well.

Next comes the part where you populate the cells which you have commented out.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel = "test"
        cell.detailTextLabel = "test2"
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Currently, the table view controller class is just the default code. Hadn't done any coding in there just yet. so its `numberOfSections` and `tableView` functions are just the standard text. Is that what I'm missing?

Comment: Updated post to reflect the code of the CreateProfileTableViewController

Comment: why number of rows are 0, you wont see anything, also make sure you have added the delegate and datasource connections as well

Comment: hmm, interesting. so my table cells are static and not dynamic right now. does this code here still apply?

Comment: You need to uncomment the section that i show. And set the text for the cells like i do. The cells are static unless you use some sort of arrays to maninpulate them. But to initiate the data you need to extend datasource and to have clickable cells you need to delegate it.

Comment: what i found was since the table cells are static, i just removed the tableView and numberOfSections lines and the data actually shows. is this not recommended?

Comment: Not sure what the default value for them are, but if the data is displayed for you i guess it's at least 1 on each of the section and rows. But for future reference, thats what you want to change if you want more cells.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks so much for the help!